# Get the exact date and time from SQL table to angular table

Tags: javascript, sql-server, angular, datetime, timezone

[image]

Getting difference when I bind

```
<td>{{items.ts | date:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a'}}</td>
```

Comment: maybe the value shown is your local time while the DB value is UTC?

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:timezone] so you're already aware of what the issue is. You need to shift the angular time by -9 hours. You can do this by using `items.ts - 9 * 3600 * 1000` I guess?